# Using html code to make a link depend on three drop down menus

Tags: html, redirect, drop-down-menu

I am working with *html* code for a web site and am trying to get the web site to link to another web site as a function of the values in three different drop down menus.

What I need is *html* code that will take the user to:

> ..../[first menu selection]/[second menu selection]/[third menu selection].html

Thank you very much,

Alex

Comment: What you are describing sounds like a 'cascading dropdown'. It involves the use of Javascript and/or server-side technology.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getUrl() {
            var part1 = document.getElementById("firstChoice").value;
            var part2 = document.getElementById("secondChoice").value;
            var part3 = document.getElementById("thirdChoice").value;
            return "http://"+part1+"/"+part2+"/"+part3+".html";
        }
        function gotoSelection() {
            var urlToGoTo = getUrl();
            alert(urlToGoTo);
            //location.href=urlToGoTo;
        }
        function setupLink() {
            var urlToGoTo = getUrl();
            document.getElementById("gotoLink").href=urlToGoTo;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="setupLink();">
    <select id ="firstChoice" onchange="setupLink();">
        <option>first1</option>
        <option>first2</option>
    </select>
    <select id ="secondChoice" onchange="setupLink();">
        <option>second1</option>
        <option>second2</option>
    </select>
    <select id ="thirdChoice" onchange="setupLink();">
        <option>third1</option>
        <option>third2</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick="gotoSelection();">goto</button>
    <a id="gotoLink" href="">goto by link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps I may just be missing something, but is there something that I need to insert into the code, perhaps at the bottom, to actually get it to link it to urlToGoTo? Right now, as written, the button takes me nowhere, and the link just takes me to my main sight.

Comment: @Besteck This has been vary helpful. Making the first of these (first series of three dropdown menus) works fine. However, when I make multiple series of three dropdown menus, all the menus take me to the link specified by the last dropdown menu in the code. Is there some way I can separate each series of 3 menus so each does not notice the others? To visualize what I am trying to do, the web site I am designing is http://tc.met.psu.edu/tcgengifs/index2.html

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need something more than just html. Fortunately, you can do this pretty easily with jQuery.

Give your drop downs a unique id like so:

```
<select id="dropdown1"> <option val="myValue1">... </select>
<select id="dropdown2"> <option val=myValue2">... </select>
...
<input type="submit" value="GO!" id="go" />
```

Then you can get the results from the drop downs with jQuery. There are probably more elegant ways to do this, but this is the basic functionality:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#go").click(function() {
    var dropdown1 = $("#dropdown1 option:selected").attr('val');
    var dropdown2 = $("#dropdown2 option:selected").attr('val');
    var dropdown3 = $("#dropdown3 option:selected").attr('val');
    var uri = "../"+dropdown1+"/"+dropdown2+"/"+dropdown3+".html";
    window.location.href = uri;
  });
});
```